# Tomcat or axis mangling a file?

Tags: java, tomcat, axis

I have a java web service I am trying to support java isn't really my area but I have to support this none the less.

A request comes into the service from a .net application with a file name and it is my job to read the file off the filesystem and spit it back out as a byte array to another service (also java but out of my control)

The problem is when they save the bytestream back out they are complaining I have somehow damaged it. But I've written a small amount of code and the file seems fine my end, they insist the array is the same size etc has anyone had a similar issue in the past ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information here to be certain.

But a while ago I worked for a legal company and had a similar issue, luckily we owned both services but I spent 6 days looking at this and then another dev spent 2 and the architect spent some time also.

We concluded our code was correctly setting the mimetypes etc and the array was correctly being written out, it was a pretty old version of tomcat (old in 2007) but it turns out when we upgraded tomcat this issue went away, therefore before you spend any more time on this I would advise the other party at least try another tomcat instance in test to see if that solves the issue.

I may be way off base though.

Comment: I have just installed a bang up to date version of tomcat and this issue has indeed vanished. Same .war file.